# Go to top of page

Tags: html, css

I created an icon at the side of my page that can be clicked to go back to the top of the page.

I thought this would be fairly simple, like so:

```css
#back_to_top{
 position:fixed;
 right:0px;
 bottom:80px;
 padding:10px;
 background-color:#fff;
 opacity:0.5;
 border-radius:10px 0px 0px 10px;
 cursor:pointer;
}
#back_to_top img{
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
}
#content{
  height:9999px;
}
```

```html
<a id="top_of_page"></a>

<div id="content">loads of content</div>

<div id="back_to_top">
 <a href="#top_of_page">
 <img src="media/top.png">
 </a>
</div>
```

However, when I click the icon it actually moves down the page by the same amount of pixels each time.

- I have no other anchors or anything else with a similar ID.
- My anchor tag is the first tag in my body.
- my 'loads of content' is all generated dynamically from php.

I know its working in the snippet but I can't share a full example, however, any ideas why this might act this way, would be really appreciated.

Comment: If you can't demo it it's **really** hard to diagnose it.

Comment: Well `<body>` has padding by default, so your `<a id="top_of_page">` is not *quite* at the top of the page.

Comment: did not any JavaScript in the code?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol margin not padding, but yes in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding an `a` element with `href="#"` should do the trick.

Here you have an example of it working:

```html
<h1>MOON</h1>
<div style="height: 700px;"><small>scroll down</small></div>
<a href="#">To the moon!</a>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, removing the anchor tag and adding the id to the body tag also worked but am going with this option because I think it would be better practice

Comment: Glad it worked. Can you check this as the correct answer so it is removed from my questions list? Thanks.

Comment: This is also a good use case for progressively enhancing with JavaScript. You can with JavaScript, for example, have it smoothly scroll you to the top of the page and not pollute your address with a '#' character if JS is enabled, and fall back to a regular targetless anchor (href="#") if JS is disabled.

Comment: This only works if scroll is to be done to the extreme top.

Comment: This will reload page :D

Comment: @NguyênNgôDuy it won't unless some other code is interfering with this.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use the Javascript `window.scrollTo` method. Passing in 0,0 will scroll the page to the top left corner instantly.

Syntax: `window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord)`

x-coord - Pixels along horizontal axis

y-coord - Pixels along vertical axis

This method allows you to scroll to any point on the page.

Comment: Thanks! this was very helpful to me. I had a button tag which i couldn't just insert an a tag in, which when pressed goes to top of page in a step by step form until submit.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you want to use a link tag <a> or a <button> tag you have two simple approaches.

For a link tag:

```
<a href='#'>To Top</a>
```

is all you need.

For a button tag:

```
<button onclick="window.scrollTo(0,0)>To Top</button>
```

Both of these work well.